# What is the best position for a gate hinge?

Tags: hinges, gates

Below you have the size of the gate three possible positions for the hinge
Considering the size of the gate what is the best position for hinges? I want the gate to swing in the direction indicated by the arrows (toward my driveway)
[image]

Edit: I believe that there are major differences between the three positions. The gate will open the same way in the end, pivoting around the vertical axis of the hinge. 
However a) and b) will transmit the torque created by the weight of the gate to the 4x4
For c)...not so much. It will be mostly supported by the screws that will attach the hinge to the gate and to the post

And here is the design that I have in mind, but it will be longer. I might use 
[image]
or use this
 [image]

Comment: I assume that there ought to be some kind of reference image, but I can't see nothing. Your comment is also the only one, so it's funny not seeing who You relate to :) Please, edit You question and,. maybe, Your comment.

Comment: I have helped install a number of large gates as you have attempted to sketch here. Your hinge position in all three drawings appear to be in pretty much the same position in all 3 sketches. I would be more concerned about what material the gate is made of  because of its potential weight and the type of hinges you plan to use. Your sketch suggests a bottom pivot, since the gate extends beyond the hinge to the left. If so I presume there will be a top pivot?

Comment: I don't know what suggested a bottom pivot but there no intention to have that. This will be for a horizontal fence about 60" high. The gate is 8' long. I intend to use cedar boards spaced equally (this design https://i0.wp.com/i143.photobucket.com/albums/r134/jenlb78/blog/0-fence2.jpg) 
See my note for the rest of your questions

Comment: A cedar gate 8' wide is going to be really heavy even with the anti-sag hardware. I'm also a little confused by your hinge drawings. Is the hinge not on the end of the door but actually a ways in from the end? From the looks of it, all of your hinge examples will only allow the door to open 90 degrees.

Comment: that is correct. This solution was imposed by the fact that that post can not be very close to an existing one ..see here for an explanation. http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/71832/i-need-to-join-my-fence-with-my-neighbors-cant-use-his-post-how-do-i-dig-the This gate will close a space that is next to my garage. The other option would be to have two gates but I am afraid that I might not be able to maintain the alignment of the horizontal boards because the gates will both sag in time.